# Why a public class needs to be imported in package other than it's own?

Tags: java, inheritance, package

I didn't get any specific answer to this question; If a class is public, then why it needs to be imported during inheritance in another package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is how it works.

You can have multiple classes with same name in different packages. So to tell your code which class you want to use you need to import packages so that you can use the specific class without full qualified name.

On the other hand if you will like to use another class with same class name you will need to use its full qualified name.